# jquery: fire a function when a specific div loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire a function when a specific div is load.
by searching I found that `onload` is not functioning on div .

so I tried it by an image that work perfect But problem is that it fire the function only one time . for example when I refresh the page it fire the function but if I again refresh the page it can't fire the function again.. why is it happened ?

*Any suggestion please*

**EDIT**

```
<div id="divID">
  <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="image"/>
</div>

$('#divID').load(function() {
   // code to function
 });
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you out: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29

Comment: Could you please post some code so that we can help you? How are you genereting your DIV?

Comment: Have you tried using the .live() function in jQuery? Its use has solved similar sorts of problems for me before http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the function inside a script tag after the div closing tag
Example

```
<div>
//something inside
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//call the function here 
functionName();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If #divID is loading in delay . You can use timeout function as below

setTimeout( function () { //Do something }, 5000); });

5000 is delay of 5 secs